# execute python script as specific user by apache webserver

Tags: python, linux, apache, hadoop

I want my website to connect to a hadoop database by python with kerberos authentification.
The problem is that by default python gets called as apache user.
For the authentification I have two specific groups added to a specific user so he is able to connect and read tables.

I already tried to use mod_wsgi with specific user but in the server log I still receive authentication failed response from impala. Maybe it's because I can only specify one group in the line "WSGIDaemonProcess connection user= group= threads=5"

Is there any other, maybe easier way I don't see ?

My python script is called by PHP mabye is there a way to set the user and group which is executing?

System:
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.3 (Ootpa)
Apache 2.4.37
Python 3.6.8

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 1) Hadoop isn't a database 2) PHP has ODBC drivers, so why Python? 3} Sounds like you're not using kinit which is what actually determines what hadoop user your script uses, not the OS process